# Großschreibung von Hauptwörtern und schnelles Lesen

Tags: spelling, capitalization

Es gibt Studien, dass deutsche Leser einen Text langsamer lesen, wenn alles kleingeschrieben wird.

Das könnte aber auch an der Gewohnheit liegen.

Ich erinnere mich, gehört zu haben, dass es eine Studie gibt, in der englische Leser einen englischen Text mit großgeschriebenen Substantiven zu lesen bekamen.

Kennt irgendjemand diese Studie und ihre Ergebnisse und weiß, wo man sie findet?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Die [Kölner Beiträge zur Sprachdidaktik (1/2005)](http://www.uni-koeln.de/ew-fak/Deutsch/projekte/koebes/KoeBeS1.pdf) beschreiben Studien aus dem Jahr 1989, ich zitiere eine Zusammenfassung und die Ergebnisse (Hervorhebungen von mir - schien mir sinnvoller, als ganz viel auszulassen). Englische Leser werden hier nicht erwähnt; ich kann mir aber gut vorstellen, dass das Ergebnis in dem Fall nicht wesentlich anders wäre als bei den Niederländern. Außerdem las ich anderswo, dass in einer der Studien englischsprachige Deutsche als Versuchspersonen auftraten und diese wohl häufig gemeint sind, wenn auf eine Studie mit englischen Lesern verwiesen wird.

> Beim Streit um Sinn und Unsinn der satzinternen Großschreibung (Beispiele besonders heftiger Pros und Kontras bietet das Sammelbändchen von Digeser 1974) ist eine interessante Asymmetrie zu beobachten: Ihre Gegner weisen auf die Rechtschreibprobleme für den Schreiber hin, ihre Befürworter auf den Nutzen für den Leser. Das Lese-Argument lautet, dass durch bessere Gliederung des Textes eine schnellere Sinnentnahme möglich sei. Da der Mensch erheblich mehr liest als er schreibt, biete es sich an, eher diese überwiegende Tätigkeit, das Lesen, zu erleichtern. Das Gegenargument lautet, dass man ohne satzinterne Großschreibung viel kostbare Unterrichtszeit anderen wichtigen Dingen widmen könnte.
>
> Es ist deshalb wichtig zu klären, ob die Großschreibung den Lesevorgang tatsächlich erleichtert. **Es könnte ja auch sein, dass es nur die Macht der Gewohnheit ist, die uns zu dieser Annahme gelangen lässt.** Im Hinblick auf diese Fragestellung erlangen **einige experimentelle Studien** besondere Bedeutung, die eben dieses zu überprüfen versuchten, vgl. u.a. **Bock, Hagenschneider & Schweer (1989) sowie Gfroerer, Günther & Bock (1989)**. Um den Faktor der „Gewohnheit“ auszuschließen, waren die wichtigsten Versuchspersonen nicht Deutsche, sondern deutschkundige Niederländer, die zwar aufgrund ihrer Sprachkenntnisse auch die deutsche Schreibung kennen, aber **Lesen im Niederländischen gelernt haben**; hier werden nur Satzanfänge und Eigennamen großgeschrieben.
>
> Die Untersuchungen brachten überraschende Ergebnisse: Auch für die niederländischen Versuchspersonen **stellten die Regeln der deutschen Großschreibung eine Hilfestellung dar, die den Leseprozess beschleunigten**. Sie konnten Texte **in ihrer eigenen Muttersprache** (!) mit den fremden satzinternen Großbuchstaben ohne Verständnisprobleme **schneller lesen** als solche mit der ihnen vertrauten gemäßigten Kleinschreibung. Detailanalysen der Augenbewegungsmuster ließen den Schluss zu, **dass in der Tat der Orientierungscharakter der Großbuchstaben dafür verantwortlich war** (Gfroerer et al. 1989).
>
> Dieses Ergebnis leuchtet dann ein, wenn man sich klar macht, was das Auge bei der gemäßigten Kleinschreibung zu leisten hat. *diese bietet dem auge nämlich ein homogeneres bild graphisch mehr oder weniger gleich großer buchstaben: zwar ist nach wie vor das vierlinienschema erhalten, aber optische orientierungspunkte fehlen.* **Aus einem Bild wie in dem Beispielsatz, den Sie gerade gelesen haben, muss  nun die sprachliche Struktur herausgefiltert werden. Diesen notwendigen Analysen scheint die deutsche satzinterne Großschreibung entgegenzukommen**, sie bietet dem Auge eine Hilfe an. Durch die nicht nur rein optische Vorstrukturierung erhält das Auge graphische Zusatzinformationen über funktional wichtige Stellen des Satzes, und dies sind im deutschen Satz eben die Kerne von Nominalgruppen. Sie sind zwar nicht die „Hauptwörter“ des Satzes, aber offenbar seine „Hauptstellen“; wie im ersten Kapitel erläutert, besteht die Grundstruktur des deutschen Satzes aus dem Verb und seinen Ergänzungen. **Wenn der Kern jeder Ergänzung (allgemeiner: jeder Nominalgruppe) durch einen Großbuchstaben ausgezeichnet wird,  kann der Satz dadurch direkt strukturiert werden, was sich positiv auf die Lesegeschwindigkeit auswirkt.**

Comment: ..was neues gelernt..

Comment: Ich frage mich nur, ob denn nicht eine Grossschreibung der Verben eine noch vorteilhaftere Leseerleichterung bedeutete.

Answer (score 7):

Actually astonishing that German is AFAIK the only language with capitalization of substantives. Reading this question, I remembered this little experiment, **TRY to read it! :)**

inner letters mixed

> I cnduo't bvleiee taht I culod aulaclty uesdtannrd waht I was rdnaieg.
> Unisg the icndeblire pweor of the hmuan mnid, aocdcrnig to rseecrah at
> Cmabrigde Uinervtisy, it dseno't mttaer in waht oderr the lterets in a
> wrod are, the olny irpoamtnt tihng is taht the frsit and lsat ltteer
> be in the rhgit pclae. The rset can be a taotl mses and you can sitll
> raed it whoutit a pboerlm. Tihs is bucseae the huamn mnid deos not
> raed ervey ltteer by istlef, but the wrod as a wlohe. Aaznmig, huh?
> Yaeh and I awlyas tghhuot slelinpg was ipmorantt! See if yuor fdreins
> can raed tihs too.

inner + first letter mixed

> I dloucn't ebeilve taht I lcuod utllaacy tsnredanud awht I was
> irdenag. sUnig hte eidbcrline poewr of the umhan nimd, ccrdiaong to
> aecrersh at biCagmdre eivUnirsty, it esdon't eattmr in hawt droer the
> teltres in a rwod are, the lnoy ropamintt nthig is that hte rfsit nad
> alst eltetr be in the hgrit aclpe. The rest acn be ttoal mses and oyu
> acn tilsl aerd it ouithwt a rebplom. hiTs is ecuasbe hte muahn mind
> does ont ared every leettr by iletsf, but hte orwd as a hlwoe.
> maiAzng, uhh? Yeah nad I lwyaas hugthot lisneplg was mprnotait! eSe if
> oyur nridfes acn raed iths oto.

all letters mixed

> I onlucd't ieebvel ttah I udloc talyulac rsddetanun hwat I swa
> radgeni. sngiU eth inrdebelic rweop fo hte nmauh imdn, dorcincga ot
> arceehsr ta meaiCrgbd yvisUntier, it deson't ramtet in athw rored eth
> erlttes ni a rwod rae, hte noyl atomirnpt nhgti si ttha hte tsfir and
> last letert eb in het girth leacp. eTh sret anc be tolta ssem dna ouy
> cna litsl eard it wohutti a elrpomb. ishT is secbaeu het mahun mnid
> dose tno aerd verye leettr yb efsilt, btu hte orwd sa a leohw.
> agzmnAi, huh? Yhea nda I awlyas utgtohh lgniespl aws optnrimta! eSe if
> uoyr resfdin acn eadr siht oto.

<sub>original text</sub>

<sub>I couldn't believe that I could actually understand what I was reading. Using the incredible power of the human mind, according to research at Cambridge University, it doesn't matter in what order the letters in a word are, the only important thing is that the first and last letter be in the right place. The rest can be total mess and you can still read it without a problem. This is because the human mind does not read every letter by itself, but the word as a whole. Amazing, huh? Yeah and I always thought spelling was important! See if your friends can read this too.</sub>

---

It works better with text in your native language, because your are more used to look/shape of words. It also shows clearly how important the first & last letter is. Its a very good proof to me that the capitalization in German is highly useful, kind of **syntax-highlighting** ;)

It also make [Speed Reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_reading) much easier to me, its not so easy to mix up a adjective/participle with a substantive, you can better scan the text for keywords (mostly substantives) and its easier to localize redundant fill words (e.g. *of the*,...)

Here some further links I had on this interesting topic:

- http://www.ruediger-weingarten.de/Texte/Capitalization.pdf  also mentioning the Bock study from Oregon answer
  Maybe the English studies you were looking for, but behind paywall
- https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2005-14045-001
- https://doi.org/10.1007/s00426-008-0168-0

Someone should write a script with auto capitalization of all English substantives in a webpage. On my way to the patent office...

Comment: +1 for comparing noun capitalization to syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Oregon actually strange that the linguistic researchers of the studies linked to in our answers dont take this into account!? Pretty obvious proof when millions of developers use it to analyse code faster...Also the option to mix up the inner letters was known afaik since 2003...

Comment: Since at least 1976 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typoglycemia#References

Comment: @debilski thx very much, i was searchin for scientific term on this...

Comment: @Hauser Note that *typoglycemia* is by no means an accepted scientific term. I’ve only posted the article because it references that PhD thesis from 1976. Apart from that, the article does not help much with explaining the scientific background.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: As these topics are often intermixed (without being a lingusit): Both topics are on two ends of a path. One asks whether some changes can make it easier and faster to read. On the other hand letter permutations are means to increase brain activity (reconstruction needs energy) and asks under which condition the reading speed goes down to 0.