# Heißt es „in Anhang A“ oder „im Anhang A“?

Tags: article, style, reference

Die Frage stellt sich mir beim Verweisen auf einen Anhang einer Arbeit. [Ich hab da zwar etwas gefunden](http://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/35146/sbj/in-anhang-c-im-anhang-c/), doch so recht konnte mich das auch nicht überzeugen. Streng genommen scheint mir *im Anhang A* korrekt, eleganter hingegen *in Anhang A*. Gibt es da eine Empfehlung?

Comment: Ich finde die Frage eigentlich gut, aber in einem Deutsch-SE wäre es wohl durchaus angebracht Groß- und Kleinschreibung anzuwenden...

Comment: @Quodly http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1704/gro%C3%9Fschreibung-von-hauptw%C3%B6rtern-und-schnelles-lesen gibt Gründe, die Großschreibung beizubehalten.

Comment: @Chieron: Interessanter Link, vielen Dank.

Comment: @Quodly: Ihre Antwort an Gerhard kann als Retourkutsche verstanden werden, was vielleicht nicht wirklich angebracht ist. Ich möchte Gerhard gerne zustimmen, dass das konsequente Ignorieren der Groß- und Kleinschreibung in einem Forum, in dem es um die korrekte Anwendung der deutschen Sprache geht, wohl eher unangebracht ist. Dann auf einem einzelnen (Tipp)Fehler, den man aus technischen Gründen auch nicht mehr korrigieren kann, herumzureiten, muss nicht sein. Wir meinen es doch gut mit den Fragestellern, die ja wohl fragen, um die Deutschkenntnisse zu erweitern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beides ist richtig, nur gemischt werden sollte es nicht.

*Im Anhang A* referenziert einen Anhang des Namens *A*.

*In Anhang A* referenziert einen Anhang des Namens *Anhang A*.

*Im Kapitel 1* und *In Kapitel 1* und ähnliche Varianten sind auch in Gebrauch.

Die *In*-Variante klingt etwas besser in meinen Ohren, ist aber nicht immer sinnvoll bzw. möglich, wenn zum Beispiel keine expliziten Kapitelnummern angegeben werden oder Anhänge keine Buchstaben als Bezeichner aufweisen.